# How do I mention my heterogenous skills on my CV?

Tags: job-search

I recently got my diploma as computer networks engineer. In our university, we have to choose between three options: Telecommunications, information security, and embedded systems. I chose the latter because I wanted to extend my field of knowledge, and I have even done my graduation project in this domain.

Now, as I am looking for a job in the computer networks, I didn't know how to manage this experience because some recruiters don't give it much attention. So the 6 months of my graduation project will be useless. Some others say that I don't look too proud of my graduation project.

How should deal with these skills? How can I mention it in my CV?

Comment: You've already asked this at  http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/21109/skills-diversity-pardox Rather than posting a new one, can you edit your existing question?

Comment: @Kvothe I suggested (via flag) that the other should be deleted.  I only saw it after answering this, and this one seems to be the second draft.

Comment: really ? -1 because the question exiested ? it was a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches you can take, depending on whether the focus is on the topic or the project.

The first is in how you list your diploma.  Instead of just "Computer Networks Engineer", you can say "Computer Networks Engineer (concentration in embedded systems)".  I did this for my degree; at the time my university didn't have an undergraduate degree in computer science (!), so you had to call it out this way if that's what you were pursuing.  (The conventional way to do computer science at the time was to approach it through a major in Applied Math.)

The second is to list the project explicitly (like some do for selected coursework).  People sometimes do this for internships and thesis projects; this sounds comparable if it was a six-month project (assuming that wasn't just half an hour a week or something).  If this is a characteristic of your degree program, then you're not the only person facing this question: ask your school's placement advisors what they recommend, or ask around among your fellow students to see if there is a consensus.